# Understanding orientation, aspect ratio and CSS pixels on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, screen-orientation, aspect-ratio

For my current project, I need to optimize a page layout in landscape mode for mobile devices. Can you help me to understand the different ways that the browser window size is measured?

I am working with an Android smartphone with hardware pixel dimensions of `720 x 1280` pixels.

**Portrait Mode**
In portrait mode, when I use JavaScript to get the `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and ~Height, I get the result `980 x 1394`.

When I use the following CSS...

```
  html {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

... Chrome Development Tools reports that the size of the body is `980 x 1546`.

[image: 720 x 1280 smartphone in portrait mode]

**Landscape Mode**
In landscape mode, things seem even more complex. In my test, I explicitly CSS set the dimensions of the whole `<html>` tag to `100vw` x `100vh`, and the `body` width and height to `100%`.

[image: html element in landscape mode]

However, JavaScript reports the `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` as `980 x 460`, while Chrome Development tools shows the dimensions of the `html` and `body` elements as `980px x 556px`, although neither of these elements fills the screen width or height.

[image: body element in landscape mode]

A `<main>` element whose width is set to `200vh` and whose height is set to `100vh` fills the entire width of the screen in landscape mode, but leaves a gap in the vertical direction, despite the fact that Chrome reports it to have dimensions of `1112px x 556px`.

[image: main element in landscape mode]

It would also be very helpful to know what exactly the different dimension properties are measuring, so that I can understand how they should be used.

EDIT:

To reply to @Kaddath: No, I had not configured a viewport meta tag. When I add the tag `<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">`, the dimensions change. In particular the `` `clienttWidth` in portrait mode becomes the screen width in hardware pixels, divided by the `devicePixelRatio`, which makes perfect sense. The `clientHeight` appears to be the height of the screen in CSS pixels, minus the height of the app bar and the built-in button bar.

[image: body portrait with viewport defined]

In portrait mode, the values for `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` are not so easy to explain.

[image: body landscape with viewport defined]
[image: main landscape with viewport defined]

Comment: _“My aim is to get the <main> element to fill the available screen space completely in both portrait and landscape modes.”_ - and how exactly would 100 vw and vh not already achieve this? I don’t get what’s with all the “JS measures this, JS measures that …” here, how is that supposed to be relevant to anything in regard to your stated goal.

Comment: And you haven't even began with iOS dimensions yet! By the way, have you configured any viewport meta tag, and if yes, how is it set?

Answer (score 0):

To better understand how browser work on different situation try to call you function with

setTimeout(showSize,300);

onresize doesn't fire correctly on all browsers.

Also try window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight.

It is very much to explain but you will learn.

You can also read https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/